# Unable to inject a @Service in a Spring Boot Test

Tags: spring-boot

I'm receiving a Null Pointer Exception when injecting a @Service into a @SpringBootTest (part of a Spring Boot 2 application).
Here is the skeleton of the Service class:

```
@Service
public class CustomerService {

    public Customer insertCustomer(Customer customer){
        /* Logic here */ 
        return  customer;

    }

}
```

And the Test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class CustomerTest {


   @Autowired
   CustomerService service;

   @Test
    public void testDiscount() {
        Customer customer1 = new Customer("ABC"); 
        service.insertCustomer(customer1);   
        assertEquals(5, customer1.getDiscount());
    }

}
```

Do I miss any other annotation in the test class to make it working?
Thanks

Comment: how are you launching this test class?

Comment: `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`?

Comment: Can you post the full exception stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` at test class level to load all necessary beans. And also make sure your package name to avoid `@ComponentScan` annotation.

So simply you can do like this:

**under src/main/java**

```
package com.customer.service;

@Service
public class CustomerService {

   public Customer insertCustomer(Customer customer) {
        /* Logic here */ 
        return  customer;
   }
}
```

**under src/test/java**

```
package com.customer.service;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CustomerTest {

   @Autowired
   CustomerService service;

   @Test
   public void testDiscount() {
        Customer customer1 = new Customer("ABC"); 
        service.insertCustomer(customer1);   
        assertEquals(5, customer1.getDiscount());
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't include the @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) because Eclipse couldn't find it.  I manually added the "import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;" now it works fine!